# JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion on OneToMany Relationship in Objectify

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jackson, objectify, jsonidentityinfo

To serve a backend for an Android App i am using `Google App Engine` together with `Objectify` (4.0.3b).

On the backend I have a simple `User` Entity, which has a `list of Users` (friends) as relationship.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private String email;
    @Load
    private List<Ref<User>> friends = new ArrayList<Ref<User>>();

    private User() {
    }

    public List<User> getFriends() {
        ArrayList<User> friendList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (Ref<User> ref : this.friends) {
            friendList.add(ref.get());
        }
        return friendList;
    }

    public void setFriends(List<User> friends) {
        List<Ref<User>> refs = new ArrayList<Ref<User>>();
        for (User user : friends) {
            refs.add(Ref.create(user));
        }
        this.friends = refs;
    }

}
```

Now when I have following Users stored in the Database for instance : `user1` and `user2`:

`user1` has `user2` in his friend list and vice versa

When trying to fetch a User object (that has the above ***cycle reference***) from my Endpoint, the Android client throws the following exception:

`com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]...`

In this post [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/) they recommend to use `@JsonIgnore` on the field or the getter/setter method.
But on the client side i need to access the friends list by these getter/setter methods (from the generated client library object), so this doesn't help me.

Another tip is to use [@JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences), which in my case can't be applied since `ManagedReference` and `BackReference` would pointto the same `friends` field.

What I think could solve my Problem is the [@JsonIdentityInfo](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity) Annotation which is available since `Jackson 2.0`.

My problem now is that I don't know how I can use this Annotation with Google App Engine.
GAE uses `jackson-core-asl-1.9.11`, which unfortunately does not have the `@JsonIdentityInfo`, as it obviously is depending on a version below 2.0.

Does anybody know, how I can use the latest Jackson Version (2.4) in Google App Engine to use the @JsonIdentityInfo feature?

Or is there a better approach for my problem?

Comment: I have the same issue, Do you find a scalable solution to this problem? It's working when I use `@JsonManagedReference` and '@JsonBackReference` from ` com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.*` package, but it's not a a good fit because we should not use this package since it is not documented...

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to define a DTO class to use as a return parameter for your endpoint and use that to flatten the JSON response (meaning not sending the infinite loop of friend's friends).